# Woocomerce как сделать разные модели товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите как сделать разные  модели товара таблицей как это реализовано на этом сайте 
http://fishing-service.com/product/dvojnik-gamakatsu-double-21-ns/

Comment: Сайт по ссылке изменится и вопрос потеряет смысл. Почти та же ситуация, что и тут: [В: Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83?s=1|0.4409)

Answer (score 1):

Показанный в примере сайт не на WordPress.

В WordPress - WooCommerce есть аналог - вариативный товар. Инструкций создания такого товара можно найти немало, например, [здесь](https://wp-lessons.com/dobavlenie-variativnogo-tovara-v-internet-magazin-woocommerce). Ну а дальше блокировать стандартный вывод информации о товаре справа от картинки и вывести все вариации во вкладку. Всё это можно сделать средствами WooCommerce.

Comment: Это не вопрос, это спам ;)

Comment: @Visman точно, не сообразил. Будем закрывать тогда)

Comment: Та нет, это реальный вопрос))

Comment: Ну тогда я ответил ) Тут не принято давать ссылки на коммерческие сайты.

Comment: Прошу прощения тогда, просто не знал как еще обьяснить. А можете подсказать, если магазин будет примерно на 20000 товаров, Wordpress справится с этим без жутких тормозов?

Comment: Я лично делал на 14000 - никаких проблем. А, вообще, WordPress может выдерживать очень высокие нагрузки. Почитайте мою статью про 10,000 соединений в секунду на WordPress: https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/